# How to ignore some static library at compile time

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, ios4

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to ignore a static library at compile time if the project already exists with similar library?

I am creating a framework in which I require to have the static library to utilize the scanning mechanism. However, the project I am trying to utilize this project also have such library, hence I am curious if there is any mechanism to ignore such library at compile time? Doesn't matter either from the framework or project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once had a similar case, where a library I wrote required some common open source components, which were used by many developers.

The best solution we found was to not link those components into our library, provide a list of these components, and to require the user of our library to include those components.

Comment: +1 for correct and perfectly fine solution. That is the way those things should be handled.

Comment: I guess thats the best option to forward with. Thanks Ahti.